# Read old/previous/past console log entries from an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, logs, console

I know there are plenty of ways to receive real-time log messages from an iPhone - e.g. the Console app on a Mac, Apple Configurator, and `cfgutil syslog`. But is there a way to look back at older messages, say from an hour before I plugged the device into my Mac?

I have macOS 10.13 and iOS 11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that a way to do this is to generate a sysdiagnose and AirDrop it to your computer. The sysdiagnose tarball contains a file called system_logs.logarchive which can be opened with Console.